# How to find a jQuery selector (using :contains) result set's complement

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

What is the best way to get the complement of a jQuery selector's result set? I want to do something like the following:

```
jQuery(this).find("div:contains('someValue')").show();
```

But I want the complement of this selection hidden:

```
jQuery(this).find("div:not(:contains('someValue'))").hide();
```

Is there a more elegant solution to this than just executing the complementary selector? An alternative I can see is finding all divs first, storing the result, and filter this:

```
var results = jQuery(this).find("div");
results.find(":contains('someValue')").show();
results.find(":not(:contains('someValue'))").hide();
```

But that doesn't seem that much better. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this,

```
jQuery(this).find("div").hide();
jQuery(this).find("div:contains('someValue')").show();
```

Comment: Well, sometimes we don't have to look very far :) Why didn't I think of that

Comment: But why not just use `$('div:not(:contains("someValue"))', this).hide();` then? The others are visible anyway...

Comment: @Simon That's not true in my situation, because I'm filtering a set of divs based on a textbox value, when using backspace some of these divs have to be shown again.

Answer (score 3):

```
var results = jQuery(this).find("div"),
    selector = ":contains('someValue')";

results.filter(selector).show();
results.not(selector).hide();
```

as [@Simon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1004893/simon) mentioned in the [comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12316948/how-to-find-a-jquery-selector-using-contains-result-sets-complement/12317053#comment16528772_12317053) there is a way to improve this particular solution:

```
var results = jQuery("div", this),
    selector = ":contains('someValue')";

results.filter(selector).show();
results.not(selector).hide();
```

Comment: This looks very clean, but the filter and not methods each loop over the result set so Claudix's solution might be faster I think?

Comment: @Jeroen Moons: there is `.each()` in his code as well. How it is not an iteration?

Comment: this solution is probably faster than claudix', for even better performance use the context parameter instead of find() because find is extremly slow, especially on something generic like divs: `var results = $('div', this);`

Comment: It is 1 iteration as opposed to 2 iterations. Filter loops over the results, and not does this again. His solution loops over the results once, and checks each item.

Comment: @Simon is jQuery(this).find("div") slower than jQuery('div', this) ?

Comment: @Jeroen Moons: yep. Using context is a bit faster

Comment: Ok didn't know that, I'll keep it in mind. Thanks for your response, AntGuider's solution seems the simplest to me.

Comment: @Jeroen Moons: and you can even improve it using the new knowledge about contexts! ;-)

Comment: Yes, I'm converting my entire script to use the context param now ;)

Comment: @Jeroen Moons: there is a brief googling results http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-speed But I remember there was some better example there

Comment: just wanted to make sure and with something simple as a div selector, it seems that find() actually is faster than context: http://jsperf.com/context-vs-find-much-elements

Comment: Thanks Simon, seems best to decide in each situation where speed really matters which is more performant. As a rule of thumb I'll use context for complex selectors and find for simple ones.

Comment: @Simon: may be just because of `document` is used for context

Comment: As a reference, other context, find is still faster :P http://jsperf.com/jquery-context-vs-find

Answer (score 1):

Well, I think your code is fairly good, but another option could be running this single statement:

```
jQuery(this).find("div").each(
    function() {
        var me = $(this);
        var f = me.is(":contains('someValue')") ? "show" : "hide";
        me[f]();
    }
);
```

Comment: This seems more efficient than zerkms' solution but looks a bit messier.

Comment: Better use filter() instead of is()

Comment: @Jeroen Moons: you could reduce the code by eliminating verbosity, but I agree it's quite messy. @Simon: filter() does not return a boolean but a reduced set. In my code, the boolean returned by `is` lets me switch between `show` and `hide`. The complement is done with a fast javascript statement instead of a jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

```
/** $.grepl 
*   uses a regular expression for text matching within an internal $.grep.
*/

$.extend({ 
 "grepl": function(el, exp){ 
  exp=new RegExp(exp,'gi'); // create RegExp
  return $( 
   this.grep( el, function(n,i){ // run internal grep
    return el[i].textContent.match(exp) != null; // match RegExp against textContent
   })
  );
 }
});

$.grepl( $('div'), '^.*someRegexp.*$' ).css('display','none'); // usage of the function
```

I know that this does not exactly use the ":contains" expression, but the result should be the same.